Why is the melting point of copper higher than gold which in turn is higher than silver?
In a d-block group, as we go down, the effective nuclear charge increases. The increase in effective nuclear charge would in turn result in greater strength of metallic bonding. So as we move gown the group, one would expect the strength of metallic bonding to increase, as the no. of unpaired electrons remain generally constant except for some exceptions. This fact is reflected in the melting point also which when going down the group generally increases. However, the melting point order of group 11 elements is Cu>Au>Ag rather than the expected order Au>Ag>Cu. Why is it so that the melting point of copper surpasses that of silver and even gold?? Similarly the melting point order of group 12 elements is Zn>Cd>Hg rather than Hg>Cd>Zn. The exceptionally low melting point of mercury can be explained by it's typical structure at room temperature. However why melting point of Cd>Zn??
Note:- I am a high school student so please kindly keep the answer more explanatory without going much into quantum effects.

Transition metals are signficantly dependent on their metallic bonding. Because copper in its metallic bonding will form ions with charge of 2+ unlike silver and Gold who form ions with 1+ charge, copper forms stronger metallic bonds. You can see this as copper has the lowest 2nd Ionization energy.
Gold again more readily forms +2 state than silver so its metallic bonds are stronger. Another important factor is its crystal structure however copper, silver and Gold have same crystal structure
Zinc and Cadmium both have filled d orbitals so their d orbitals can't participate in metallic bonding giving them really weak metallic bonds. Mercury due to Relativistic effects has weakest metallic bonds hence it is a liquid. Not really a strong trend between Zinc and Cadmium
A user in this question has provided inredible detail which I am not able to so if you are still confused, here is a link to understand more
Melting and boiling points of transition elements
